# Using BeautifulSoup, is there a way to target all elements with that contain a class name except the ones that contain an additional class name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am looking to see if there is a way to `find_all` elements that have a certain class name, but remove the elements that contain an additional class name.

```
<div class="abc">1</div>
<div class="abc def">2</div> #Do not select
<div class="abc">3</div>
<div class="abc">4</div>
<div class="abc">5</div>
<div class="abc">6</div>
<div class="abc">7</div>
<div class="abc def">8</div> #Do not select
<div class="abc">9</div>
<div class="abc">10</div>
```

I know I can grab all of the class elements like this:

```
elements = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'abc'})
```

But is there a way to limit the results to the elements that also contain the class `def` are not included?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS selector:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = """\
<div class="abc">1</div>
<div class="abc def">2</div> #Do not select
<div class="abc">3</div>
<div class="abc">4</div>
<div class="abc">5</div>
<div class="abc">6</div>
<div class="abc">7</div>
<div class="abc def">8</div> #Do not select
<div class="abc">9</div>
<div class="abc">10</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.select('[class="abc"]'):
    print(tag)
```

Prints:

```html
<div class="abc">1</div>
<div class="abc">3</div>
<div class="abc">4</div>
<div class="abc">5</div>
<div class="abc">6</div>
<div class="abc">7</div>
<div class="abc">9</div>
<div class="abc">10</div>
```

---

Or: Using `bs4` API:

```py
for tag in soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.attrs.get("class") == ["abc"]):
    print(tag)
```

Comment: @cards Yup, better use `.get()`, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

You can "deactivate" (just make consider them as a *single* string) multi-valued attributes by passing an extra parameter when creating the *soup*: [`multi_valued_attributes`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#multi-valued-attributes). Then you can keep your code the same.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser", multi_valued_attributes=None)
```